# SSRS Report Server - Patch update Dec 2022 - Subscription's based on Day or Month can not modify or create new

Tags: reporting-services, powerbi, subscription

Dec 2022, the SSRS/PowerBI report server had a patch/update.
Since that time, I am no longer able to modify or create new subscriptions with the Schedule time of day or month.

If the subscriptions is not modified, it continues to work but unable to modify the time or distribution list on an NEW or Existing subscriptions if the schedule is based on Day or Month.

Subscription (new or modified) based on HOUR are able to save an execute.

Has anyone else experience this problem?

To save the subscription

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug we informed Microsoft about in November and finally convinced their team that it was an issue earlier this month. We have a ticket number but apparently the only way to ask about it is to call. :smh:

The workaround is to use a Shared Schedule instead of a Report Specific Schedule.

[image]

The shared schedule needs to be set up before the subscription. Go to Site Settings by clicking on the Gear icon in the upper right. Then go to the Schedules page and click on New Schedule.

[image]